# How to get the validity date range of a price from individual daily prices in SQL

Tags: sql

I have some prices for the month of January.

```
Date,Price
1,100
2,100
3,115
4,120
5,120
6,100
7,100
8,120
9,120
10,120
```

Now, the o/p I need is a non-overlapping date range for each price.

```
price,from,To 
100,1,2 
115,3,3 
120,4,5
100,6,7
120,8,10
```

I need to do this using SQL only.
For now, if I simply group by and take min and max dates, I get the below, which is an overlapping range:

```
price,from,to
100,1,7
115,3,3
120,4,10
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags from the question.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: *"I need to do this using SQL only"* Eve4ry RDBMS uses a different dialect of SQL, there is no "SQL only" solution, as it'll could well be specific to the RDBMS you are using. What have you tried so far as well, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  The simplest solution is the difference of row numbers:

```
select price, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by price, order by date) as seqnum2
      from t
     ) t
group by price, (seqnum - seqnum2)
order by min(date);
```

Why this works is a little hard to explain.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the adjacent rows are identified by the difference in the two values.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. problem got solved. 
Understood the logic on how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Lag.price,Lag.[date]  AS [From], MIN(Lead.[date]-Lag.[date])+Lag.[date] AS [to] 
 FROM 
    (
        SELECT [date],[Price] 
        FROM    
            (
                SELECT [date],[Price],LAG(Price) OVER (ORDER BY DATE,Price) AS LagID FROM #table1 A
            )B 
        WHERE CASE WHEN Price <> ISNULL(LagID,1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
    )Lag
JOIN    
    (
        SELECT [date],[Price] 
        FROM
            (
                SELECT [date],Price,LEAD(Price) OVER (ORDER BY DATE,Price) AS LeadID FROM [#table1] A

            )B 
        WHERE CASE WHEN Price <> ISNULL(LeadID,1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
    )Lead
ON          Lag.[Price]             =   Lead.[Price]
WHERE       Lead.[date]-Lag.[date] >=   0
GROUP BY    Lag.[date],Lag.[price]
ORDER BY    Lag.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method using ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING

```
    SELECT price, MIN([date]) AS [from], [end_date]  AS [To]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, MIN([abc]) OVER (ORDER BY DATE DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) end_date
        FROM
            (
                SELECT *, CASE WHEN price = next_price THEN NULL ELSE DATE END AS abc
                FROM
                    (
                    SELECT      a.* , b.[date] AS next_date, b.price AS next_price 
                    FROM        #table1 a
                    LEFT JOIN   #table1 b
                    ON          a.[date] = b.[date]-1
                    )AA
            )BB  
    )CC
    GROUP BY price, end_date
```